# OpenPyXL - Check if a word exists in a series of words within a cell

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to automate some work that uses excel by checking through the cells and if certain keywords exists, give a different output. At the moment I am using:

```
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

...

if sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value in bl_list:
    print("value found")
```

This works if the input is exactly the same as what exists in bl_list, ie. apples in apples, but I want to try and make it more dynamic so that it could search through a sentence and find the keywords. ie. I want 10 apples would return true as apples exist, etc.

I have bl_list as a set since that is faster than using a list, although there is no issue modifying it to suit.

Cheers in advance for any help!

Comment: If you're using a set the you can use set logic to do the searching. Simply spllit the value of a cell (after checking it's a string) and check for the intersect. Not that the comparison is going to be the limiting factor here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is a string you could use

```
for bl in bl_list:
    if sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).find(bl) != -1:
        print("value  {} found".format(bl))
```

Alternatively, this search for any common elements between the splitted value of the cell and your set

```
if len(list(set(sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value.split(' ').intersection(bl_list))) > 0:
    print("value found")
```